# Not enough vertical spacing with booktabs and siunitx

Tags: tables, siunitx, booktabs

I am using siunitx and booktabs, but I need a bit more vertical space between my units.

Here is a picture of my problem:

[image: siunitx spacing problem]

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{range-phrase=-,
            detect-all,
            decimalsymbol=comma,
            round-mode=figures,
            round-precision=3,
            range-units=single,
            per-mode=fraction,}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
    \centering
        \begin{tabular}[]{llr}
            \toprule 
            Parameter & Symbol & Wert   \\ 
        \midrule 
            A       &A2         &\SI{1096}{\kg \per \cubic \meter } \\ 
            B       &B2         &\SI{0,422}{\watt \per \meter \per \kelvin} \\ 
            C       &C2         &\SI{3220}{\joule \per \kg \per \kelvin}    \\ 
            D       &D2         &\SI{0,0274}{\kg \per \meter \per \second}      \\ 
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I think what you are looking for is an increased row padding as explained here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/31704/118712

Comment: On a side note: your first unit should be `\kg\per\cubic\metre` otherwise the cubic won't be displayed.

Comment: And if you're looking for a quick-and-dirty solution, try adding `[2ex]` after each row, like this: `A       &A2         &\SI{1096}{\kg\per\cubic\meter }\\[2ex]`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Column and row padding in tables](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31672/column-and-row-padding-in-tables)

Comment: Not related: You don't need to put `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` in modern LaTeX installations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The automatic way uses the `cellspace` package, which ensures a *minimal* vertical spacing at the top and bottom of cells in columns with specifier prefixed with a certain letter – default is `S`, but as you load siunitx, we have to use another letter, definable as an option at loading time. Here is how it goes with your table:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{range-phrase=-,
            detect-all,
            decimalsymbol=comma,
            round-mode=figures,
            round-precision=3,
            range-units=single,
            per-mode=fraction,}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[column=O]{cellspace}
\setlength{\cellspacetoplimit}{3pt}
\setlength{\cellspacebottomlimit}{3pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
    \centering
        \begin{tabular}[]{llOr}
            \toprule
            Parameter & Symbol & Wert \\
        \midrule
            A &A2 &\SI{1096}{\kg \per \cubic \meter } \\
            B &B2 &\SI{0,422}{\watt \per \meter \per \kelvin} \\
            C &C2 &\SI{3220}{\joule \per \kg \per \kelvin} \\
            D &D2 &\SI{0,0274}{\kg \per \meter \per \second} \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Bernard has given an answer using `cellspace`. The package `nicematrix` (which provides several tools to draw tabulars and mathematical matrices) has a slightly different approach: all the columns of the environments `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix` are of type 'cellspace' and you have two keys `cell-space-top-limit` and `cell-space-bottom-limit` similar to the parameters `\cellspacetoplimit` and `\cellspacebottomlimit` of `cellspace`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{range-phrase=-,
            detect-all,
            decimalsymbol=comma,
            round-mode=figures,
            round-precision=3,
            range-units=single,
            per-mode=fraction}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\NiceMatrixOptions{cell-space-top-limit=3pt,cell-space-bottom-limit=3pt}


\begin{table}[htbp]
    \centering
        \begin{NiceTabular}[]{llr}
            \toprule 
            Parameter & Symbol & Wert   \\ 
        \midrule 
            A       &A2         &\SI{1096}{\kg \per \cubic \meter } \\ 
            B       &B2         &\SI{0,422}{\watt \per \meter \per \kelvin} \\ 
            C       &C2         &\SI{3220}{\joule \per \kg \per \kelvin}    \\ 
            D       &D2         &\SI{0,0274}{\kg \per \meter \per \second}      \\ 
            \bottomrule
        \end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: Ouput of the above code]

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to enlarge `\arraystretch˙and change the way of writing units:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{range-phrase=-,
            detect-all,
            decimalsymbol=comma,
            round-mode=figures,
            round-precision=3,
            range-units=single,
            per-mode=symbol,}   % <---
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
    \centering
    \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2} % <---
        \begin{tabular}[]{llr}
            \toprule
            Parameter & Symbol & Wert   \\
        \midrule
            A       &A2         &\SI{1096}{\kg \per \cubic \meter } \\
            B       &B2         &\SI{0,422}{\watt \per \meter \per \kelvin} \\
            C       &C2         &\SI{3220}{\joule \per \kg \per \kelvin}    \\
            D       &D2         &\SI{0,0274}{\kg \per \meter \per \second}      \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]